# Make permanent connection with MySQL (Apache Spark)

Tags: mysql, linux, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If I execute these commands in spark-shell it correctly returns the data in the "people" table:

```
val dataframe_mysql = spark.sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_spark").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "people").option("user", "root").option("password", "****").load()

dataframe_mysql.show
```

The problem is if I close spark-shell and return it open, the connection to the database is not maintained.

Comment: That's because the connection is retained inside the JVM. You don't seem to be using the right tool for the job. Spark isn't a database, it's a computing engine. It's not possible to keep that connection if you exit the spark-shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Spark's [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#using-the-shell), `SparkContext` and `HiveContext` get created inside the spark shell (when `spark-shell` command is executed) with `HiveContext` defined as `SQLContext`. As the connection is mapped to `SQLContext`, closing the spark shell will mean you won't be able to access `SQLContext` and hence, you won't be able to connect.

[Here's](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bigdatasupport/2015/09/14/understanding-sparks-sparkconf-sparkcontext-sqlcontext-and-hivecontext/) another reference:

> When you run spark-shell, which is your interactive driver
>   application, it automatically creates a SparkContext defined as sc and
>   a HiveContext defined as sqlContext.